# Python ElementTree - select element attributes based on value of 1 attribute

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to select only 1 element row based on the value of an attribute. For example, in the code below I only want to select the name and age where the title ='President'. How would I go about doing this?

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Report>
        <Element name='Bob' age='32' title='President'></Element>
        <Element name='Sue' age='25' title='Vice-President'></Element>
        <Element name='Mary' age='44' title='Secretary'></Element>
    </Report>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

for target in root.findall('.//*[@title]'):  
    print(target.tag, target.attrib)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an XPath expression to get your Element:

```
root.find("*[@title='President']")
#          ^ Seach in child elements as well
#           ^ Filter items with a predicate
#            ^ the "title"-attribute must be 'President'
```

To get your name and age attributes, you can do:

```
element = root.find("*[@title='President']")
print(element.attrib["name"], element.attrib["age"])
```

You can find explanation on standard library supported XPath [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax).

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helps. How would I pull the President element if it was nested deeper in the XML, like there were elements in between Report and Element?

Comment: Does it work for you with the predicate `".//*[@title='President']"` ?

Comment: @GrizzlyMcGee: avoid "extra questions" in comments. The original question has been answered. You should accept the answer.

Comment: @Talon that does not work for me. I get this error - SyntaxError: cannot use absolute path on element. But mzjn is right, you answered my original question. I'll ask a new question about that issue. Thank you for your help.